# How to fix misaligned icons in buttons depending on size of button

Tags: css, sass, icons, font-awesome, glyphicons

I'm not using a specific framework, and created my own icon font. However, when I write out the icon inside a button it's fine, but if I change the height of the button the icon tends to misalign getting a space above that shoves it down too low. Anyone have any ideas on how to make this work in a stable way?

Tried line-height and using flex, but flex moves the entire button. And line-height makes no change whatsoever.

```
<button class="button icon"><i class="icon-plus" /></button>

.button {
...
 &::after {
      content: '\e00E';
      font-family: $font-family-icons;
      color: $white;
      font-size: 1.2rem;
      width: 1.2rem;
      height: 1.2rem;
      position: absolute;
      top: calc(50% - 0.6rem);
      left: calc(50% - 0.6rem);
      @include animation-zoom-in();
    }
}

i {
  position: relative;
  font-family: YouCruitIconFont, sans-serif !important;
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: inherit;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;

  & + span {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 0.5rem;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
.button {
...
 &::after {
      content: '\e00E';
      position:absolute;
      font-family: $font-family-icons;
      color: $white;
      font-size: 1.2rem;
      width: 1.2rem;
      height: 1.2rem;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
      @include animation-zoom-in();
     }
}
```